# I have a problem creating separate table for images

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a small database for some products and O need to add multiple images for one product.

I've created a separate table to add images URL with product_id, image_id.

The thing is how do I set the product id in images table while I'm adding a new product!

Comment: First add the product to database and then get the product id `mysqli_insert_id($conn);` and after that add the image product id with retrieved product id.

Comment: Any decent (recent) book or tutorial on PHP and MySQL will cover this kind of thing

Comment: @AnkitSingh is on the right path but there is a more easy method assumming your product table has a `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` the most easy would be to use MySQL's [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function  and direclty use it in the INSERT like `INSERT INTO images VALUES(image_path, product_id) VALUES('some_path', LAST_INSERT_ID())`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Easier in what sense?

Comment: *"Easier in what sense?"* @Strawberry well the extra code is in PHP or MySQL query it does not really matter that much it's one param less you would not have to protect against SQL injections with parameterized queries but matter of taste i geuss..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the product_id is auto increment primary key, and when you insert a record in products table, the new id is generated that can be obtained using LAST_INSERT_ID() function of mysql, or if you are using PDO, you can use [lastInsertId() PDO fucntion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) for this as well.

If you prefer MySQL function then it can be used in insert query for images as :

```
INSERT INTO images VALUES(product_id, image_id) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), yourimageid)
```

Or using PDO:

```
$product_id = $db->lastInsertId(); //where $db is pdo object
```

and after that you can use $product id in next insert queries.

Comment: Yes i treid the first solution and it worked perfectly, thanks